# What type of bike is this? Brand?

Tags: repair, identify-this-bike

I found this bike and I don't know anything about bikes but I was hoping to figure out a brand for it.

Also, it doesn't have working breaks; I want to repair the brakes myself but I don't know where to start.

Any help or advice is greatly appreciated.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to the site - Consider joining [chat] for a more responsive chat about your options (to avoid this question growing badly)

Answer (score 1):

You found a bike?  Normally the process is to advise the local police station and hand it in.  After 3-6 months you can legally claim ownership if the owner doesn't come forward, or the item goes to a periodic Police auction.

Cover yourself - don't risk get accused of stealing it.

---

The bike I can see in the pictures is missing some parts.  At the bare minimum you will need to acquire

- Front disk brake caliper, pads, and cable.  And mounting bolts
- EITHER Rear V brake arms, pads, cable and outer
- OR Rear disk brake rotor, caliper, pads, cable, and bolts.

The rear brake depends on whether the hub has rotor mounts, and if the frame has caliper mounts for a disk brake, or if it has a rim brake track.

I also can't see a front derailleur, but the rear seems to be present.

Its certainly fixable, but you absolutely need two working brakes to ride it at all.

---

The brand does not matter in the slightest - it appears to be a 2005-2010 vintage, or perhaps a bit newer if its a BSO.  The photos don't really show detail.

Answer (score 1):

The ROCKSHOX Dart 1 front fork would imply it was a lower mid to mid-tier bike at the time of manufacture.  It was likely equipped with mechanical disc brakes due to the lack of brake mounting posts on the rear seat stays. I would estimate it could be a 2005 to 2012 based on the fork. As far as what brand, as already stated it is of little importance as far as replacing parts goes. Although it does resmble a DiamondBack Response or a BikesDIrect knockoff model. Almost any modern parts will be superior to what it had originally. With a little research on this site or others you may be able to get used replacement parts that will get it ridable. On side note check the front fork or ask a local bike shop to check it. A replacement fork may make it cost prohibitive to getting it ridable.